# Can't restore Firefox bookmarks from JSON backup

Tags: firefox

Before reinstalling Ubuntu, I backed up my bookmarks as a JSON file using Firefox 7.0a1-32bit on Ubuntu 10.10.

Using Ubuntu 11.04, when trying to restore the backup, I get the following error:

[image: Unable to process the backup file]

Using Firefox 4.0.1, same message using Firefox 7.0a1-64bit

Is it a known problem, or did I do something wrong?

Comment: Create a new json backup and restore it, just to see if works. It could be that your json got corrupted.

Comment: You might get more debugging information from the Error Console -- it's in Tools (under "Web Developer" submenu in newer versions), or you can open it with Ctrl+Shift+j.  Open that, then click "All", then "Clear", and then try to import your bookmarks & see if any messages appear.

Comment: You could try running the backup file through http://jsonlint.com to check it's valid JSON. If not that would confirm the first comment that your backup is corrupt. Also, this question is quite old, if the problem is no longer relevant this question should probably be closed.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards